# UNIOn with two queries not returning json values

Tags: sql, sql-server

Wrapping the head around to get the value of union as json returned in a separate new column

```
select col9,col10,col11, 
    (select col1,col2,col3 from mytable1 for json path
    union 
    select col1,col2,col3 from mytable2 for json path) as myjson,
col13,col14
from maintable
```

but i am getting an error

**Msg 1086, Level 15, State 1, Line 64
The FOR XML and FOR JSON clauses are invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables, and subqueries when they contain a set operator. 
To work around, wrap the SELECT containing a set operator using derived table or
 common table expression or view and apply FOR XML or FOR JSON on top of it.**

Comment: `FOR JSON` needs to go in the outer query, just like the error is telling you to do.

Comment: Why not `SELECT` and `UNION` and then apply `FOR JSON PATH` on the result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per my comment, why not perform the UNION prior to using `FOR JSON PATH`:

```
SELECT  col1, col2, col3
  FROM  (
        SELECT col1,col2,col3 FROM mytable1
        UNION
        SELECT col1,col2,col3 FROM mytable2) a
  FOR JSON PATH
```

This `UNION`s the two tables together and then uses `FOR JSON PATH` on the amalgamated result.

Comment: +1. Remember SQL is basically set mathematics. `UNION` is the union of two (or more) datasets. How you do that in a hierarchically structured object representation?

Comment: but there are other columns too above the two queries like edited in my question

Comment: @urrru Why didn't you post the whole question originally?